# How to increase decimal precision on percentage format using Twig's Intl extension?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, intl, twig-extension

I have a decimal number with 4 digits and a scale of 4. (Max is 0.9999 and min is 0.0000)

I'm using Twig and its [intl extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html). When I want to render a percent number, decimals are rounded.

```
{% set decimal = 0.0850 %}
{{ decimal|localizednumber('decimal','double','fr-fr') }} //WILL OUTPUT "0,085"
{{ decimal|localizednumber('decimal','double','zh-cn') }} //WILL OUTPUT "0.085"
{{ decimal|localizednumber('decimal','double','ar-bh') }} //WILL OUTPUT "٠٫٠٨٥"
{{ decimal|localizednumber('percent','double','fr-fr') }} //WILL OUTPUT "8 %"
{{ decimal|localizednumber('percent','double','zh-cn') }} //WILL OUTPUT "8%"
{{ decimal|localizednumber('percent','double','ar-bh') }} //WILL OUTPUT "% ٨"
```

I would like to see `8,5 %` in French, `8.5%` in chinese and `% ٨٫٥` in arabic.

I tried to add the `double` parameter, but it does not change the precision.

As I am using Symfony, I tried to declare 2 decimals in number format:

```
<!-- lang-yml -->
#config/twig.yaml
twig:
    #...
    number_format:
        decimals: 2
```

It seems that the Intl extension is overriding these settings.

I know that I can do something like

```
{{ (decimal*100)|localizednumber('decimal','double')}}%
```

But the `%` symbol can be before the result in some languages, in French, there is a non-breaking space before the `%` symbol.

Do you see my error? Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can't be done directly with Twig Intl extension you are using.**

It doesn't have a parameter to set the precision, it simply instantiate the `NumberFormatter` with the formatting style of your choice, and will use that to `format()` your value.

Check the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405508/symfony-4-1-twig-extension).

---

**There is another extension which does have more options: https://github.com/twigphp/intl-extra**

With this one you can specify all the attributes supported by `NumberFormatter`, as shown [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

You would use it like this:

```
{% set decimal = 0.0850 %}
{{ decimal|format_number(style='percent', locale='fr', {min_fraction_digit: 1}) }}
```

---

Alternatively, **you could write your own extension by leveraging on `NumberFormatter`**.

The pattern that `NumberFormatter::PERCENT` uses by default is `#,##0 %`, which does not include decimal precision. You can define your own pattern following [these rules](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#details) so it does.

Or simply call to `setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 1)` to specify the the minimum number of decimal numbers you are interested in.

For example:

```
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 1);
```

The final implementation is up to you, and if you'd need to use it within a Twig template you'd have to [create your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405508/symfony-4-1-twig-extension) (official Symfony [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)).

See more examples [here](https://3v4l.org/UltjH).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I already upvoted it, but I want to explore a last idea before accepting it. Because I see in source code that the `localized_number`function is calling via an attribute the max number of digit `getAttribute(NumberFormat::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS)`. It seems that it is possible to set this global parameter. I will try to explore this last idea, but I think your answer is the best solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right, you could use `setAttribute()`. I'll update the answer to account for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is perfect. I have created my own extension by leveraging NumberFormatter and I now use my extension to autoselect the good language which could come from session or user preferences. This extension seems interesting, too.